# An integral inequality on a disc about twice derivatives.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, partial-derivative, integral-inequality

Denote $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ has a continuous twice derivative on the disc $D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq1\}$, which satisfy $f(\partial D)=\{0\} $, where $\partial D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\}$, please prove:

> $$\iint_Df(x,y)(\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2})dxdy\leq0$$

I tried using the polar coordinate, but can't put one foot forward.

Comment: Polar coordinates is the wrong way. Hint - use a multivariate version of integration by parts(=divergence theorem), with the formula $\partial_x^2f + \partial_y^2f = \nabla \cdot \nabla f $(divergence of gradient)

Comment: Would you mind explaining it clearly? I'm shamed to say I know only some basic facts about multivariate version of integration.

Comment: Remind yourself how 1D integration by parts is derived: Its an integration of $(fg)'=f'g+g'f$. As $(fg)'$ is an exact derivative, you know how to integrate it exactly, which gives you the boundary terms. Its the same for the divergence. Say $F$ is vector valued, $g$ is scalar valued, then $\nabla\cdot (Fg) = g\nabla \cdot F + F\cdot \nabla g$. An exact divergence can be integrated on $D$ using the divergence theorem, getting you boundary terms. I promise that the answer drops out when you use $F=\nabla f$ (cf first comment), and the boundary condition to deal with the boundary terms.